CodeIgniter file not working on localhost - dashboard redirection
I am experiencing an issue where when I run a CodeIgniter file on localhost, I am redirected to the dashboard. I have followed the steps provided in the CodeIgniter documentation, but the issue still persists. Is there a solution to this problem?
{
    "description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name": "codeigniter/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/codeigniter",
        "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.4"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*"
    }
}


no i'm using php8.2

What type of server?

Do you rename the file env to .env ?
If not then rename it and change the server variable from production to development.

You should check your config.php, .htaccess and .env files' base_url
